# Column chart transform values changing intermittently leading to chart not being shown

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular-highcharts

Sometimes on rendering of chart, the values of css transform in column chart changes due to which chart doesn't render properly even though the data is present.

I tried debugging the code and found the following in the html rendered:

```
 data-z-index="0.1" class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-1 highcharts-column-series highcharts-tracker" transform="translate(130,400) scale(1 0.001)" >
```

While when the chart renders properly, this is the following html:

```
 data-z-index="0.1" class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-1 highcharts-column-series highcharts-tracker" transform="translate(130,45) scale(1 1)" >
```

translate(130,45) scale(1 1) gets changed to translate(130,400) scale(1 0.001)" because of which the chart can't be seen.

Comment: Hi @Akhil Singh, Could you show the problem in some online code editor?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3sgjv8e2/

Comment: Thank you, but it looks like all the points are visible. Could you describe more precisely what is the problem?